# Load wav audio file in memory in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, audio, wav

i have a wave file (mono, 16bit), and i have to write a program in C that fills an array with its content. (Not only the header informations)
I can't use libraries, i must write it from scratch.

I need to do this for subsequently do various operations with the file. (such normalization ecc...)

Unfortunately i haven't found any compete informations about this problem, especially in C.

Would be also greatly appreciated some references to sources which describe this type of problems.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Just read the WAV file in binary mode. Whatever book you're using to learn C should have a section on binary file I/O. Look for function names like `fopen` and `fseek`.

Comment: A Google search seems to turn up plenty of example code for reading WAV files - was there some specific part that of this task that you were having difficulty with ?

Comment: Thank you for promptly response, the problem is that i have found only the way to load the header informations, i haven't found how to load the content of the file in an array. The binary mode should be a great idea, but perhaps it is not so simple because of the structure of wav files, maybe there might be problems with the fact that some parts of the file are litte endian and some others big endian?

Comment: so the problem is not to get the contents into memory, but also to extract information from the file into structured data into memory?

Comment: to get the content into memory it is just fopen(), fstat(), malloc(), fread(), fclose();

Comment: I have to fill an array (which will be loaded in memory) with the entire content of the file. My problem is that i have not a clear idea of ​​what kind of data I'm going to work, array of doubles I think I understand.

Comment: Yes, i used fopen etc...but i'm not able to decode the informations in the right way, i don't know how to store the (apparently unreadable data) in an array (of doubles?).

Comment: why doubles?!? try bytes (unsigned char), so you can read byte by byte the information you need (according to definition, like wikipedia)

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you!! :) I'll try to read the file byte by byte and store it in an array!! (if you can provide me an example it would be fantastic). I still have a big question: must i care about the data format BIG or LITTLE endian??

Comment: @LucaP. Yes, you absolutely do need to care whether multi-byte data from disk (or network) is little or big-endian. Since these are WAV files, the PCM data will be most likely be little-endian 16-bit data. Take care when loading.

Comment: Ok, I managed to open the file and read it byte by byte, and yes, some informations are big-endian and some other are little-endian. My question now is: when I interpret the data, must i care of the type of processor (big e. or l.e.) on which the code will run??

Answer (score 0):

> some informations are big-endian and some other are little-endian.

This is not true according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) (little-endian byte order).

> My question now is: when I interpret the data, must i care of the type
>   of processor (big e. or l.e.) on which the code will run?? –  Luca P.

Yes, you must, but such care can be limited to programming portably. For example, to get a 2-byte signed value stored in little-endian order, you could write

```
value = 256*(int8_t)byte_array[i+1] + (uint8_t)byte_array[i];
```

this works on little-endian as well as on big-endian processors.